# flutter pub publish returns error 69: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter, publish, flutter-pub

I have a severe problem for a few days now, since I'm the maintainer of a Flutter package that needs to be updated to run properly. Whenever I try to publish it by running `flutter pub publish` I get the output:

```
Connection closed before full header was received
pub finished with exit code 69
```

Things I have tried so far:

- Updated Flutter (my previous version was 2.8.1 which also resulted in this error, so the issue wasn't introduced by the update)
- Disabled all my firewalls
- <del>Tried different internet connection</del> (I tried to connect my cellular to another tower a few miles away)
- `flutter clean && flutter pub get`

I have already made a [report on GitHub](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3317), but I'm not sure if this is really a problem with Flutter Pub, since nobody replied so far. I also didn't publish for a month or so.

My environment is:

- MacOS 12.1 (21C52)
- `flutter --version`

```
Flutter 2.10.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 097d3313d8 (6 days ago) • 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
Engine • revision a83ed0e5e3
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

- `flutter pub version`: Pub 2.16.1

How can I fix this issue?

#### EDIT

I was able to publish in a different state with my cellular network, coming back home (on the go in my state, not home per se) resulted in the same problems again. I suspect my ISP is related, so I doubt something can be done here. Unfortunately, I failed to log my IP, but it should've been changed all the way.

It would be helpful to figure out what connections exactly are blocked, so I can report to my ISP. The verbose log delivers nothing in particular.

Final bits of my verbose log:

```
IO  : Writing 13602 characters to text file /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/.cache/stream_transform-versions.json.
FINE: Contents:
    | {"name":"stream_transform","latest":{"version":"2.0.0","pubspec":{"name":"stream_transform","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","repository":"https://github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","version":"2.0.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"async":"^2.5.0","pedantic":"^1.10.0","test":"^1.16.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/2.0.0.tar.gz","published":"2021-02-08T20:39:42.781950Z"},"versions":[{"version":"0.0.1","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.1","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.1.tar.gz","published":"2017-05-02T21:18:12.730976Z"},{"version":"0.0.2","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.2","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.2.tar.gz","published":"2017-05-05T18:25:02.549723Z"},{"version":"0.0.3","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.3","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.3.tar.gz","published":"2017-05-06T01:17:59.200588Z"},{"version":"0.0.4","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.4","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.4.tar.gz","published":"2017-05-07T05:08:23.736115Z"},{"version":"0.0.5","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.5","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.5.tar.gz","published":"2017-05-08T19:29:30.337971Z"},{"version":"0.0.6","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.6","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.6.tar.gz","published":"2017-07-11T17:49:52.346766Z"},{"version":"0.0.7","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.7","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.7.tar.gz","published":"2017-07-12T21:37:21.881557Z"},{"version":"0.0.8","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.8","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.8.tar.gz","published":"2017-08-04T21:29:35.335027Z"},{"version":"0.0.9","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.9","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=1.22.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.9.tar.gz","published":"2017-08-07T17:50:45.071548Z"},{"version":"0.0.10","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.10","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.20.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.10.tar.gz","published":"2018-02-01T17:36:18.358790Z"},{"version":"0.0.11","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.11","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.20.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.11.tar.gz","published":"2018-03-26T21:54:37.981388Z"},{"version":"0.0.12","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.12","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.20.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.12.tar.gz","published":"2018-06-01T22:54:20.690496Z"},{"version":"0.0.13","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.13","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.20.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.13.tar.gz","published":"2018-06-08T19:40:12.169781Z"},{"version":"0.0.14","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.14","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.20.0 <2.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.14.tar.gz","published":"2018-06-13T23:18:37.103439Z"},{"version":"0.0.14+1","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.14+1","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.0.0-dev.20.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^0.12.20+13"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.14%2B1.tar.gz","published":"2018-07-18T22:32:17.283866Z"},{"version":"0.0.15","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.15","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^1.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.15.tar.gz","published":"2019-02-12T23:44:03.199387Z"},{"version":"0.0.16","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.16","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^1.0.0","pedantic":"^1.5.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.16.tar.gz","published":"2019-03-12T22:16:35.569606Z"},{"version":"0.0.16+1","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.16+1","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^1.0.0","pedantic":"^1.4.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.16%2B1.tar.gz","published":"2019-03-13T17:02:43.561690Z"},{"version":"0.0.17","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.17","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^1.0.0","pedantic":"^1.5.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.17.tar.gz","published":"2019-03-26T16:40:37.009736Z"},{"version":"0.0.18","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.18","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^1.0.0","pedantic":"^1.5.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.18.tar.gz","published":"2019-04-29T16:21:13.938771Z"},{"version":"0.0.19","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.19","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"test":"^1.0.0","pedantic":"^1.5.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.19.tar.gz","published":"2019-05-03T18:25:14.940260Z"},{"version":"0.0.20","pubspec":{"version":"0.0.20","name":"stream_transform","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","environment":{"sdk":">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"build_runner":"^1.0.0","test":"^1.0.0","build_web_compilers":"^2.0.0","pedantic":"^1.5.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/0.0.20.tar.gz","published":"2019-11-05T21:24:00.648789Z"},{"version":"1.0.0","pubspec":{"name":"stream_transform","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","version":"1.0.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"pedantic":"^1.5.0","test":"^1.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/1.0.0.tar.gz","published":"2019-11-20T21:38:34.753041Z"},{"version":"1.1.0","pubspec":{"name":"stream_transform","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","author":"Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","version":"1.1.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"pedantic":"^1.5.0","test":"^1.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/1.1.0.tar.gz","published":"2019-12-03T23:09:21.926102Z"},{"version":"1.2.0","pubspec":{"name":"stream_transform","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://www.github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","version":"1.2.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"async":"^2.0.0","pedantic":"^1.5.0","test":"^1.0.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/1.2.0.tar.gz","published":"2020-02-26T19:08:01.293710Z"},{"version":"2.0.0-nullsafety.0","pubspec":{"name":"stream_transform","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","homepage":"https://github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","version":"2.0.0-nullsafety.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"async":"^2.5.0-nullsafety","pedantic":"^1.10.0-nullsafety","test":"^1.16.0-nullsafety"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/2.0.0-nullsafety.0.tar.gz","published":"2021-01-13T21:21:37.589884Z"},{"version":"2.0.0","pubspec":{"name":"stream_transform","description":"A collection of utilities to transform and manipulate streams.","repository":"https://github.com/dart-lang/stream_transform","version":"2.0.0","environment":{"sdk":">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"},"dev_dependencies":{"async":"^2.5.0","pedantic":"^1.10.0","test":"^1.16.0"}},"archive_url":"https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform/versions/2.0.0.tar.gz","published":"2021-02-08T20:39:42.781950Z"}],"_fetchedAt":"2022-03-06T17:58:20.972031"}
ERR : Connection closed before full header was received
FINE: Exception type: ClientException
FINE: package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 886:7                         BoundHostedSource._throwFriendlyError
    | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 409:7                         BoundHostedSource._fetchVersionsNoPrefetching
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                       Future.catchError
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:52                                captureErrors.wrappedCallback
    | package:stack_trace                                              Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                                captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command.dart 180:13                              PubCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27                          CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 173:24                       PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 158:20                       PubCommandRunner.run
    | package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 46:56                               runDartdev
    | /opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart 11:9  main
[+16609 ms] "flutter publish" took 16,766ms.
[   +4 ms] pub finished with exit code 69
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _DefaultPub.interactively (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:416:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      PackagesForwardCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:251:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1161:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:281:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[   +4 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 69
```

Comment: can you please provide the full error log

Comment: @RajaEhtisham Here are some more details (incl. a link to my verbose log): https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3317 (I was able to bypass the issue with a different network, but the affected network is a cellular network and the problem was also just geo constrained (same ISP worked in different location, just not in my state).

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with `dart pub publish --dry-run`. If the warnings are 0 then try `dart pub publish`. I have uploaded my package as well but didn't encounter such a question.

Answer (score 0):

consider trying:

```
flutter pub pub publish
```

instead of:

```
flutter pub publish
```