# Connection closed before full header was received ``

Tags: dart, pub.dev

Connection closed before full header was received

I have the same issue as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265574/flutter-pub-publish-returns-error-69-connection-closed-before-full-header-was-r?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C139.7880) only with a dart project.

When I run:

```
dart pub publish
```

Results in;

```
FINE: Validating package finished (27.076s).
ERR : Connection closed before full header was received
FINE: Exception type: ClientException
FINE: package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 1329:7
```

- checked all my network connections and everything seems fine there.
- waited a few hours and still the same problem is there.
- uploading the repository in individual parts, rather than at the parent.
- I’ve tried using `flutter` cli instead of `dart` cli